# SwiftUI App Lifecycle with Firebase and Xcode 12

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, ios14, xcode12

I'm getting this THREAD error `Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffeecc0bfe8)`.

Depending on how I configure my launch in `Example.App`, the console prints `no pending snapshot found` or `UIApplicationAdaptor does not conform to AppDelegate`.

Here's the code with Xcode 12 (directly from Peter Friese from Firebase, replacing `Colors` with `Example` as an app name):

https://medium.com/firebase-developers/firebase-and-the-new-swiftui-2-application-life-cycle-e568c9f744e9

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase

class AppDelegate: NSObject, UIApplicationDelegate {
  func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                   didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    print("Example application is starting up. ApplicationDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.")

    return true
  }
}

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
  @UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var delegate
  
  init() {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
  }
  
  var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
      InitialView()
           .environmentObject(SessionStore())
    }
  }
}
```

My `InitialView` looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct InitialView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var session: SessionStore
    
    func listen() {
        session.listenAuthenticationState()
    }
   
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if session.isLoggedIn {
                MainView()
            }
            if !session.isLoggedIn {
                SignInView()
            }
        }
        .onAppear(perform: listen)
    }
}
```

And my `SessionStore` like so

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import Firebase

class SessionStore: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isLoggedIn = false

    var userSession: User?
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    
    func listenAuthenticationState() {
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener({ (auth, user) in
            if let user = user {
                print(user.email ?? "")
                let firestoreUserId = Ref.FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_USERID(userId: user.uid)
               
                firestoreUserId.getDocument { (document, error) in
                    if let dict = document?.data() {
                        guard let decodeUser = try? User.init(fromDictionary: dict) else { return }
                            self.userSession = decodeUser
                    }
                }
                self.isLoggedIn = true
            } else {
                print("isLoggedIn is false")
                self.isLoggedIn = false
                self.userSession = nil
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
// Firestore
    static var FIRESTORE_ROOT = Firestore.firestore()
    
    // Firestore - Users
    static var FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_USERS = FIRESTORE_ROOT.collection("users")
    static func FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_USERID(userId: String) -> DocumentReference {
        return FIRESTORE_COLLECTION_USERS.document(userId)
    }
```

Comment: Hi David, I wasn't able to repro this. Your code looks mostly OK to me. Can you share the code for `Ref.FIRESTORE_DOCUMENT_USERID` (best to add it to the original question). Also, can you elaborate on what you mean by "depending on how I configure my launch"?

Comment: Hi, @PeterFriese. By "configure my launch," I meant, I tried to initialize Firebase in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of my `App Delegate` versus in the initializer in the `@main` struct.

Comment: I tried other things, too, like not using an `App Delegate`. Is that possible w/o choosing "App Delegate" when I first create a project? Can I initialize Firebase any other way?

Comment: If you just use Firestore, you can initialise Firebase in the initialiser of your application class - see the first code snippet in the "Start using the SwiftUI App Life Cycle" section of [my article](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-new-app-lifecycle-firebase/). Either way, this should not crash. Something else is going on. Do you use the latest version of the Firebase pods?

Comment: Yes. Let me try that and will return to this post. Thanks, Peter.